# Using select info outfile

Tags: mysql

I am trying to send the results of a query to a file using
SELECT * from TABLENAME INTO OUTFILE 'spool.txt' ;

but I can't find the resulting file

The command executes, but I don't know where to find the file.
I did some research, tried to use a full path but there are permission problems.
I did
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
to see the directory where I thought the output would go, it said
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\
But when I look in that directory the file is not there.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure `OUTFILE '<path>'` needs to be a full path matching the `secure_file_priv` path

Comment: I tried with pathname using                                                                    
         Select * from vendors into outfile 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\spool.txt';   this gave message Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement 0.000 sec

Comment: And if you use `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/spool.txt` ? Also it might be tricky because `MySQL Server 8.0` has spaces maybe configuring a other dir without spaces is beter.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of this, still same problem.  I have a book that says the syntax is correct. sigh...